# Where is the error in this? ( access query)

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
SELECT [02d1_NTS_Report_Structure].Nation, [02d1_NTS_Report_Structure].Region, 
    [02d1_NTS_Report_Structure].Territory, [02d1_NTS_Report_Structure].Zone,
    iif ([02d1_NTS_Report_Structure].Zone="-", 
        iff ([02d1_NTS_Report_Structure].Territory="-",
            iff ([02d1_NTS_Report_Structure].Region="-", 
                [02d1_NTS_Report_Structure].Nation, 
                [02d1_NTS_Report_Structure].Region),
        [02d1_NTS_Report_Structure].Territory), 
    [02d1_NTS_Report_Structure].Zone)
FROM 02d1_NTS_Report_Structure;
```

Comment: Which error? Do you get any error code/message? Or the "wrong" result?

Comment: You tell us where the error is!

Comment: yes i get an error statement. Undefined function iff in expression

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're using "IFF" instead of "IIF" in a couple places.

Try this:

```
SELECT [02d1_NTS_Report_Structure].Nation, [02d1_NTS_Report_Structure].Region, 
    [02d1_NTS_Report_Structure].Territory, [02d1_NTS_Report_Structure].Zone,
    iif ([02d1_NTS_Report_Structure].Zone="-", 
        iif ([02d1_NTS_Report_Structure].Territory="-",
            iif ([02d1_NTS_Report_Structure].Region="-", 
                [02d1_NTS_Report_Structure].Nation, 
                [02d1_NTS_Report_Structure].Region),
        [02d1_NTS_Report_Structure].Territory), 
    [02d1_NTS_Report_Structure].Zone)
FROM 02d1_NTS_Report_Structure;
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can see is that you probably should put brackets around your table name:

```
SELECT [02d1_NTS_Report_Structure].Nation, 
[02d1_NTS_Report_Structure].Region, 
[02d1_NTS_Report_Structure].Territory, 
[02d1_NTS_Report_Structure].Zone, 
IIF([02d1_NTS_Report_Structure].Zone="-", 
    IIF([02d1_NTS_Report_Structure].Territory="-",
       IIF([02d1_NTS_Report_Structure].Region="-", 
           [02d1_NTS_Report_Structure].Nation,
           [02d1_NTS_Report_Structure].Region),
        [02d1_NTS_Report_Structure].Territory), 
     [02d1_NTS_Report_Structure].Zone) 
    FROM [02d1_NTS_Report_Structure];
```

Comment: For the record, brackets aren't necessary anywhere in his whole SQL string.  Brackets are only necessary when your table or field names contain spaces.

Comment: Good to know. I totally missed the switch between IIF and IFF :)